# Error: Invalid value for <text> attribute x="NaN" in angularJS nvd3-multi-bar-chart

Tags: angularjs, d3.js, angularjs-nvd3-directives

I'm new to d3 charts, i want to use x-axis as string and my app throws `Error: Invalid value for <text> attribute x="NaN"` error.

This is my sample JSON

```
[
{"key" : "test1", "values" : [["test1", 3]},
{"key" : "test2", "values" : [["test2", 5]},
{"key" : "test3", "values" : [["test3", 9]}
];
```

So , How to pass x-axis value as string

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure this should work?
Coordinates are usually numbers and not some sort of text. Plus I don't see a single example of this directive where it uses a String for X- or Y-Axis values.

You could check out this though:
http://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/

It uses Labels as X-Coordinate, but you have to set every single X-Coordinate on this one and can't skip any points which is annoying in some cases. But if that's fine for you, I'd suggest you to try it.